# Converting plain password IN database to encrypted password using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to convert plain text password in database to encrypted password but not is not saving in database a encrypted password ?

How can i do this ?

please see this user table 
https://ibb.co/7SKTbqW

**controller**

```
public function registeraction(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:6',
    ]);

    $name = $request->get('name');
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $password = bcrypt($request->get('password')); 

    $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email','password']));      
    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
    $user->save();

    if ($user) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are retrieving the `password` value from the `$request` and modifying the value.

```
$password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
```

However, when you create the user, you're retrieving the original unmodified `password` value from the `$request` again.

```
$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email','password']));
```

Instead, this line should read:

```
$user = User::create(compact('name', 'email','password'));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try `Hash:make`**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

$password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
```